# Cannot drop column with ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, sqlite, alter-table

I cannot drop a column with `ALTER TABLE`. I create a table within SQLite:

```sql
sqlite> create table example ( "field" text not null );
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE example ( "field" text not null);
```

Then I add a column with `ALTER TABLE`:

```sql
sqlite> alter table example add column onsale bool;
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE example ( "field" text not null , onsale bool);
```

Then I try to delete it:

```sql
sqlite> alter table example drop column onsale;
Error: near "drop": syntax error
```

It's weird that the name `onsale` is not between parenthesis. Is that the reason? Is this particular to SQLite3 or is it an SQL issue in general?

Comment: ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN is supported in SQLite since version 3.35.0 Check your version

Comment: @forpas Version is 3.31.1

Comment: Then you can't use DROP COLUMN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't drop a column in SQLite prior version 3.35.

You need to create a new table. Copy from your "example" table to the new table =)

That's at least how I always do it for small tables.